# How to add a ActionListener to the close button

Tags: java

How do you add a `ActionListener` to the close button (not a `JButton` the button on the top-right)?

Comment: if (Display.isCloseRequested())
   {
    // DO STUFF
   }

Comment: Im getting an error from display

Answer (score 4):

See [Closing an Application](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/) for a discussion on this topic and a couple of solutions.

Basically you need to do two things:

1. Use the `setDefaultCloseOperation(...)` of the frame.
2. Add a `WindowListener` to the frame